# Перенос бокса vagrant на другую машину

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

Есть комп с Ubuntu на борту, на нём поднят Vagrant в связке в Virtualbox. Задача: экспортировать бокс в файл, перелить файл на флешку, воткнуть флэшку в другой комп с Ubuntu и там импортировать созданный файл в Vagrant так, чтобы он работал, т.е. по команде vagrant up запускалась виртуальная машина. Вопрос - как?

Это: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/package.html видел, но не понял что к чему

Добавление: выполнил **vagrant package** в дирректории проекта, на выходе получил файл package.box весом ~8Гб т.е. то что надо, НО: как его теперь скормить вагранту на другой машине? Пробовал **vagrant box add package.box**, ругается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё правильно, осталось сделать следующее:

```
vagrant init
```

В созданном файле `Vagrantfile` прописать box_url к package.box:

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/my-project"
config.vm.box_url = "file:///sandbox/my-project/package.box"
```

Теперь можно делать

```
vagrant up
```

Comment: там есть папка project, которая монтируется в гостевую ОС в /var/www/%project_name%, внутри папки project лежит git-репозиторий. То естья делаю так: 1. vagrant init (появляется Vagrantfile, в который я вношу указанные Вами правки), затем 2. я делаю git clone %repo_url% project, появляется папка project, затем я делаю vagrant up, так? тогда вопрос - настройки из старого Vagrantfile с другой (изначальной) машины просто вручную перенести в новый? там, настройки хоста, ssh, дирректорий и т.д.