# Vagrant - косяки SSH и не только

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant

Недавно я [задавал вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644538/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0-vagrant-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83) на тему переноса бокса Vagrant, проблема была решена, но не до конца. У меня было два бокса, оба построены на ubuntu/xenial64, НО: с одним всё в порядке, а у другого постоянные проблемы с ssh-соединением. После выполнения команды vagrant up он выпадает в бесконечный цикл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом, при попытке выполнить vagrant ssh, начинает требовать пароль от пользователя ubutnu, причём пустой пароль не принимает. Нашёл в инете какую-то инструкцию, зашёл через ВиртуалБокс в графческом режиме сбросил пасс на юзера, на рута, появилась другая проблема - папка project/ монтируется в /var/www/html/project, содержимое папки я правлю в хостовой системе в Sublie Text, изменения появляются в виртуальной машине. Если например создаю файл в виртуальной машине (например, создаю миграции через sequelize), файлы появляются ТОЛЬКО в виртуальной машине, в хостовой папке их НЕТ. Наверняка это два разных косяка, может, кто-то сталкивался?

P.S. Перенесённый бокс снёс, залил из сети новый, ubuntu/xenial64 чистый, косяки все те же самые остались. Как поправить настройки SSH (может, где-то что-то сбросить/поменять?) и как правильно слинковать папки чтобы всё редактировалось нормально? К слову, первый бокс, который переносил, тоже с нодой, и там всё работает штатно, и SSH, и линковка папки, и миграции, и всё-всё-всё.

P.P.S. Вот такое ещё бывает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавление по поводу ключей SSH.
Первая система, где всё работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вторая система, где не работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: наверно, файлы `/etc/ssh/*key` в обоих системах идентичны.

Comment: @alexander barakin можно подробнее? "в обоих" - в каких?

Comment: в вопросе вы их называете «боксами»: «*было два бокса, оба построены на ubuntu/xenial64*»

Comment: @alexander barakin добавил в вопрос. Какие именно ключи должны совпадать? мой вопрос он несколько глубже - вот я перенёс бокс со старой системы, добвил адрес файла в конфиг, да? всё запускается, нормально. новые когда боксы создаю, какие-то вот эти все траблы. может, в конфиге самого Вагранта я где-то что-то не дописываю? сейчас допустим Вы мне поможете я да, заставлю рабоатть одну отдельно взятую машину, с которой щас косяки, ну а дальше? завтра третья понадобится, опять ручками её ковырять. почему она изначально косячная создаётся? не было такого на старой системе

Comment: ну что, товарищи? какие будут идеи? вчера заново опять попробовал, всё работало, утром опять Authentication failure